# Does an anechoic chamber take mainly effect on the sound from inside or outside the chamber?

Tags: acoustics

per [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absorption_(acoustics)), an acoustic anechoic chamber is

> a room designed to absorb as much sound as possible. The walls consist of a number of baffles with highly absorptive material arranged in such a way that the fraction of sound they do reflect is directed towards another baffle instead of back into the room. This makes the chamber almost devoid of echos which is useful for measuring the sound pressure level of a source and for various other experiments and measurements.

Does an anechoic chamber take mainly effect on the sound from inside or outside the chamber? Are there some measurements about the effect that an anechoic chamber takes on the sound from inside or outside?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The term anechoic itself refers only to the sound from within the chamber. As the name suggests, it produces *no echo*, and an echo can only occur as a reaction of a sound in the room.

However, most (if not almost all) of the time anechoic chambers are also acoustically isolated from outside noise, depending on their specific use case.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is there a term to refer a chamber that is mainly acoustically isolated from outside noise and does not care the echo within the chamber?

Comment: One would probably call that a soundproof room, but even then they often have measures against echoes on the inside.

Answer (score 1):

In a purpose-built anechoic chamber, the outermost wall will be concrete typically 8 inches thick and the foundation slab poured separately from that of the surrounding structure. The thick concrete walls will reflect back almost all of the sound coming towards the chamber from outside, and the separate slab will isolate the chamber from vibrations transmitted through the floor from other activities in the building.

In this case, the primary source of sound leakage entering the chamber will be via the air conditioning ducts. These will always be heavily lined with absorptive material and baffled into a labyrinth shape, but ~60Hz noise from the air-moving fans in the system will pass through the ducting with little attenuation. Since even a well-baffled chamber will *not* be anechoic at very low frequencies (less than or equal to ~60Hz), the sound energy around 60Hz will build up inside the chamber as long as the air-handling system is running.

Accurate low-frequency sound level measurements therefore require that the ventilation system be shut off for the duration of the measurements.

Answer (score 0):

To the comment about chambers that do not care about the echos...

There are also reverberant chambers, which purpose is the exact opposite of that of an anechoic chamber, that is, to keep sound reverberating in the room for a relative long time.
They are used to measure, among others, the random-incidence absorption coefficient of materials and the random-incidence scattering coefficient of geometries.
There may be adjacent reverberant rooms to measure the sound reduction index of a material (which is mounted between the two rooms).
This may be the closest scenario been asked for, as in the receiving room one cares about the sound coming from the other, adjacent room, and the resulted reverberation is also accounted for.

There are also semi-anechoic chambers, which have only one reflective surface, usually the floor. The directional diffusion coefficient of a geometry may be measured using this type of room.